# gforth base-execute syntax

Tags: forth, gforth

Some online `gforth` docs provide a seemingly [complete description of  `base-execute`'s effects](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Number-Conversion.html#index-base_002dexecute-_0040var_007b-i_002ax-xt-u-_002d_002d-j_002ax---_007d--gforth-1483):

```
base-execute       i*x xt u – j*x         gforth       “base-execute”

execute xt with the content of BASE being u, and restoring the
original BASE afterwards.
```

But the syntax for the effects seems like a lock without a key -- the page links to nothing that describes what `i*x xt u – j*x` signifies.  Some hunting turned up a [partial description of the syntax notation](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Notation.html#Notation), (which tells us that `u` is an *unsigned number* and `xt` is an *execution token*), but that's still not enough to understand `i*x xt u – j*x`.

How is `base-execute` used, and what does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what `base-execute` does you need to understand `execute` and `BASE`. I'll also explain how to read `i*x` and `j*x` in the stack effect.

`execute` works by taking an execution token `xt` and executing it. `' 1+ execute` is the same as `1+` on its own. The reason to use `execute`, though, is because you can pass `xt` on the stack, instead of having to choose it ahead of time. For instance:

```
: exec-twice dup >r execute r> execute ;
2 ' 1+ exec-twice . ( this outputs 4 )
```

`BASE` is a variable that controls what numeric base to use for input and output.
`BASE` is initially 10. So `5 2 BASE ! .` outputs `101` (which is 5 in base 2).

`base-execute` puts them together: it changes `BASE` to `u`, executes `xt`, then restores `BASE` to its previous value. Its implementation might look like this:

```
: base-execute BASE @ >r BASE ! execute r> BASE ! ;
```

Here's an example usage:

```
: squared ( n1 -- n2 ) dup * ;
: squares ( n -- ) 0 do i squared . loop ;

10 squares ( 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 )

: hex-execute ( i*x xt -- j*x ) 16 base-execute ;

10 ' squares hex-execute ( 0 1 4 9 10 19 24 31 40 51 )

10 squares ( 0 1 ... 81  we're back to decimal )
```

---

Now for `i*x xt u -- j*x`:

The stack notation documentation you linked to has most of the information you need to read the effect. `i*x -- j*x` means that *something* might happen to the stack, but it doesn't specify what. In this case, the exact stack effect depends on what `xt` is.

To know the stack effect with a given `xt`, replace `i*x` and `j*x` with the two sides of `xt`'s stack effect.

For example, if `xt` is `' .` you would look at `.`'s stack effect, which is `n --`. In that case you could think of `base-execute`'s stack effect as `n xt-of-. u --`.

Comment: Thanks!  Just plain `base-execute` is fun, i.e.:  `10 ' squares 3 base-execute` for ternary, `10 ' squares 95 base-execute`, for being cryptic, etc.

Comment: @agc: very cryptic. I could be wrong, but AFAIK, `BASE` should have a value in the range 2..36 only.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Not sure, which therefore prompts a new question: [ANSI forth BASE upper limit, to and from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004214/ansi-forth-base-upper-limit-to-and-from)