# ANSI Forth BASE upper limit vs. gforth upper limit, to and from?

Tags: radix, gforth

Fiddling with the `gforth` version of `BASE` shows that `BASE` can be used for values past those most languages permit. For example, this prints the number *0ABC (base 15950)* in decimal, and vice versa:

```
gforth -e '15950 base ! ABC decimal . cr bye'
gforth -e '2544200462 15950 base ! . cr bye'
```

Output:

```
2544200462
ABC
```

Without writing additional *Forth* words, what are the default Gforth and *ANSI Forth* `BASE` upper limits for meaningful conversions both *to* and *from* numbers of different bases?

(Ignore for the moment the complexities of mapping an existing character set to depict some arbitrary radix, or else imagine an endless fractal character set that adds little 30-150 degree serifs when new characters are needed.)

Comment: Retitled:  I've moved the goalposts on this Q. a bit.  The ANSI answer ("36") being less interesting than the `gforth`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [standard](http://forth-standard.org/standard/core/BASE), it is

> BASE
>
> ( -- a-addr )
>
> a-addr is the address of a cell containing the current number-conversion radix {{2...36}}.

So it is 2..36.

That makes sense, doesn't it?

- The lower limit is 2 because any number of digits less than 2 would be useless.
- The upper limit is 36 because that allows for 0-9 and A-Z as digits, case insensitive.

Comment: It's not clear from this answer whether the *Forth 2012 Standard* is the same as *ANSI* with regard to `BASE`.

Comment: The 2012 standard is the current Forth standard, but it is not an ANSI standard. But note that the 1994 ANS standard has the same text.

Comment: ANS94 also says: 'The value in BASE is the radix for number conversion. A digit has a value ranging from zero to one less than the contents of BASE. The digit with the value zero corresponds to the character "0".  This representation of digits proceeds through the character set to
the decimal value nine corresponding to the character "9".  For digits beginning with the decimal value ten the graphic characters beginning with the character "A" are used.  This correspondence continues up to and including the digit with the decimal value thirty-five which is represented by the character "Z".'

Comment: The online ANSI docs regarding numbers seem a bit fuzzier:  ["A.3.2.1.2 Digit conversion  *For example, an implementation might convert the characters a through z identically to the characters A through Z, or it might treat the characters [ through ~ as additional digits with decimal values 36 through 71, respectively.*"](https://www.taygeta.com/forth/dpansa3.htm#A.3.2.1)

Comment: Yes, anything above 36 is implementation dependent. But what ANSI docs do you mean?

Comment: Re "*what docs do you mean?*": In my previous comment the text in blue italics should be a clickable link to  https://www.taygeta.com/forth/dpansa3.htm#A.3.2.1

Comment: @agc: Also take a look at: https://www.taygeta.com/forth/dpans6.htm#6.1.0750. That clearly states that the values are 2..36. Of course implementations do not have to (and often do not) follow the standard, nor is it customary to check the values of such variables.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of`BASE` in Gforth *v0.7.2+dfsg1-1.1*, (for converting `ABC` to a number and back again), seems to be the unexpectedly large *960,383,882*. That number was found and tested by comparing Gforth's output with [`calc`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/calc-whatis.html) (an  arbitrary precision calculator which can whip out all 76,976 digits of `(27^3)!` in about a second), and as used below `calc` is presumed to be correct:

```
# Output Gforth calculation of (12*b^2)+(11*b^1)+(10*b^0) to
# base 10 and inversely back to base b.
b=960383882 n=ABC ; bd=$(gforth -e $b' base ! '$n' decimal . cr bye')
gforth -e "${bd} dup . cr $b"' base ! . cr bye'
calc "10*($b^2)+11*($b^1)+12*($b^0)" | xargs echo
9223372018618121954 
ABC 
9223372018618121954

# It fails here:
b=960383883 n=ABC ; bd=$(gforth -e $b' base ! '$n' decimal . cr bye')
gforth -e "${bd} dup . cr $b"' base ! . cr bye'
calc "10*($b^2)+11*($b^1)+12*($b^0)" | xargs echo
-9223372035883752001 
-A8f 
9223372037825799615
```

Tests for upper limit of `$n`, (*i.e.* the `n=ABC` in the code above) pending...

Comment: A more general formula showing how the limits of `$n` and `$b` relate, preferably with regard to `gforth`'s environmental or implementation constants, would be better.  Ideally such a formula could be abstracted to apply to other *Forth*s.

Comment: That merely shows that gforth does not check the value. That is not surprising. And the algorithm also works for other values (above 1).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, What's surprising (for *me*, if no one else) is that the conversion remains accurate for base 960 million -- at least for values lower than `ABC` anyway.  I'd have supposed it would have started returning garbage in the 100s or 1000s.

Comment: I am not surprised at all. It is inherent to the algorithm. Converting from text to a binary number is usually done in double cell format (usually 64 bit, these days), and the CPU does not care if it multiplies by a huge value or by 2, 10, 16 or 36 when converting the next digit. `960383882` easily fits in a 32 bit value. The result for the next base (`960383883`) does not fit in 64 bits anymore.

Comment: Sorry, wrong. It fits in 64 bits, but not in 63 bits (signed), that is why the result is negative: the sign bit is set. Multiplication doesn't care about signed or unsigned. And the result from calc (0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) is very likely wrong.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Re "*result from calc (0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)*":  That "*0x7FF...*" string is not in my code, please explain where it's from, and also what radix it's in.

Comment: I used another calculator (Mac) and converted it to hex.Have you never seen this notation before? Do you actually understand how conversion of text to binary works? Do you know what a sign bit is? Anyway, the decimal result you gave is 0x7FF.... etc. in hex, which is probably the highest (positive) value calc can handle. I doubt it is the correct value, which is probably > 0x7FFetc..

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, How twos complement affects number conversion maximums is certainly relevant; please include it in your answer.   [`calc`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/calc-whatis.html)'s precision should be sufficient.  (Try `calc '7^7^7'`, wait six seconds, presto 695977 digit scroll by...)

Comment: Two's complement does not affect the number conversion maximum. The size of a cell affects the numbers a cell (or a double cell) can hold. But if you give weird values to BASE (values that can never be human-readably represented anyway), and it still works out, then that does not surprise me, knowing how this is usually done. But just use values from 2 to and including 36 and you'll be fine. Anything else is "implementation-dependent".